# ignore parameter in parent css

Tags: css, import, parent

I'm working on a child theme for wordpress. 
I need to show a searchbox near the bottom of the header, instead of in the top.

So I need to replace the

```
#searchform {
top: 2.8em;
```

in the parent theme, with a

```
bottom: 2em;
```

In the child. 
Is it possibile to do that? (instead of doing top: "total height-2em")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in your child theme:

```
#searchform {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The auto value is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you cannot change the css file of the parent theme, you can override it in your child's css file as follows:

```
#searchform {
    top: auto !important;
    bottom: 2em;
}
```